# Clever work-around for my current script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently utilizing JavaScript to allow users to watch multiple videos on a page. There is one big player at the top of the page, and below it are smaller thumbnails of more videos.

In theory, it works fine. However, there is one major problem: ALL videos load at the same time as the page loads.

See [this](http://spuxystudios.com/mvibo/30day_new3/) page for reference. I have assigned JavaScript alerts to each individual videos to exemplify the problem (video1, video2, etc.).

Is there a easy fix, without having to rewrite the entire page, to have the videos load **when they are clicked on**, not when the page loads?  Here's what the code looks like so far:

Javascript that calls the video:

```
function playVideo(cap, file, streamer, alertmsg) {
    var so = new SWFObject('player/player-licensed_5_2.swf', 'ply1', '586', '330', '9');
    so.addParam('displaywidth', '586');
    so.addParam('displayheight', '330');
    so.addParam('allowfullscreen', 'true');
    so.addParam('allowscriptaccess', 'always');
    so.addVariable('skin', 'player/skins/glow.zip');
    so.addVariable('controlbar', 'over');
    so.addVariable('plugins', 'captions-1');
    so.addVariable('captions.file', cap);
    so.addVariable('dock', 'true');
    so.addVariable('image', 'landing_img/video.jpg');
    so.addVariable('file', file);
    so.addVariable('streamer', streamer);
    so.addVariable('autostart', 'false');
    so.write('player1');
    window.alert(alertmsg);
}
```

The thumbnail for the video:

```
<div class="mini_player1"> <a href="#" class="vidpic" title="">
    <!-- thumbnail-->
    <img src="images/1_panda.jpg" alt="Video 1" class="vidpic"  />
    <span class="play-button"><img src="images/yt.png"  alt="Play"></span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="content_mini_player1 cmp">
    <script>
        playVideo('<caption file>', '<videofile>', '<streamer>', 'video1');
    </script>
</div>
```

The script that 'replaces' the content in `bigplayer` with the new selected video:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".mini_player1, .mini_player2, .mini_player3, .mini_player4, .mini_player5, .mini_player6, .mini_player7, .mini_player8, .mini_player9, .mini_player10, .mini_player11, .mini_player12, .mini_player13, .mini_player14, .mini_player15, .mini_player16, .mini_player17, .mini_player18, .mini_player19, .mini_player20").click(function () {
        var player_content_id = "content_" + $(this).attr("class");
        var player_content = $("." + player_content_id).html();
        $(".big_player").html('');
        $(".big_player").html(player_content);
    });
});
```

Any suggestions? Maybe consolidate `playVideo` and the jQuery function? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in the thumbnail code, there is a random closing `</a>` tag. Unless there is code you didn't post, I'd suggest removing it.

Secondly, your jQuery can be simplified much further. Currently, you are using the following selector:

```
$(".mini_player1, .mini_player2, .mini_player3, .mini_player4, .mini_player5, .mini_player6, .mini_player7, .mini_player8, .mini_player9, .mini_player10, .mini_player11, .mini_player12, .mini_player13, .mini_player14, .mini_player15, .mini_player16, .mini_player17, .mini_player18, .mini_player19, .mini_player20")
```

Wow! That is...wow.

Assign the players a single class they can all relate to across the board, select by that class and then run the `each()` method i.e.:

```
$(".mini-player").each(function() {
    var player_content_id = "content_" + $(this).attr("class");
    var player_content = $("." + player_content_id).html();
    $(".big_player").html('');
    $(".big_player").html(player_content);
});
```

Lastly, when you call a function in a script tag like you are doing:

```
<script>
    playVideo('<caption file>', '<videofile>', '<streamer>', 'video1');
</script>
```

This WILL run the `playVideo()` function. Consolidating `playVideo()` and the jQuery code would be your best bet i.e. (using the same construct above):

```
$(".mini-player").each(function() {
    var player_content_id = "content_" + $(this).attr("class");
    var player_content = $("." + player_content_id).html();
    $(".big_player").html('');
    $(".big_player").html(player_content);
    //Add event handler
    $(this).on('click',function() {
        playVideo('<caption file>', '<videofile>', '<streamer>', 'video1');
    });
});
```

Comment: If I implemented this method, wouldn't the variables 'caption, file, and streamer' be set to a single string?

Comment: @hansupyoon Yes, you need to figure out a method to make those strings dynamic. I sure hope you aren't manually adding them right now.

Answer (score 0):

Your inline JavaScript function playVideo is going to be called when the page loads. You will want to remove it from there and do something like this:

```
<div onclick="playVideo()" class = "mini_player1">
```