# How to change parts of HTML with Javascript when a link is clicked on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Let's say I have a DIV named "videoplayer" -- inside this DIV is an image.

Is there a simple way to change the HTML code inside this DIV when a link is clicked on?

For example, this is the current DIV:

```
    <div class = "big_player" id="player1">
             <img src="whatever.jpg">
    </div>
```

When a link is clicked, I want the HTML to change to:

```
    <div class = "big_player" id="player1">
             <script>
                playVideo(file, stream, key);
             </script>
    </div>
```

What is the simplest and easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: To what end, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: When we are talking jQuery, then the click event is what you are looking for. But I recommend to read the documentation before you try to implement something complex.

Comment: @DavidThomas See this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181955/clever-work-around-for-my-current-script

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html) method, but if you want to just run a script you can do it directly..

so

```
$('linkID').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   $('#player1').html('new html here');

});
```

or for running scripts you might prefer (*if it fits your needs*)

```
$('linkID').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   playVideo(file, stream, key);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript:

```
<a id="link" onclick='change()' href="#">Link</a>

<script>
function change()
{
  var script = document.createElement('script');            
  script.innerHTML = 'playVideo(file, stream, key);';
  p = document.getElementById("player1");
  p.innerHTML = "";
  p.appendChild(script);
}
</script>
```

or as Gaby pointed out, run it directly

```
<script>
  function change()
  {
    playVideo(file, stream, key); 
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What if there are multiple videos to call? I have 12 videos in total, the method you kindly shared only supports one link/video.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

try this:

```
$("img").on("click", function(e){

var content = "<script>" +
                   "playVideo(file, stream, key);" +
              "</script>";

$(this).parent().html(content);

});
```

just make sure the **playVideo()** and all its parameters is existing. Send me a feedback if it didnt work. We might use *eval()* if it failed.

Comment: What if I have multiple videos/thumbnails?